# How to get path of all last existing subfolders in a specific directory?

Tags: python, path, filepath, subdirectory

I have a main folder and nested folders in that and some files in only end of the folder chain.
eg. main/fol1/fol2/fol3/files, Now

fol1 can be fol11, fol12,.., (i mean in 'main' folder there are multiple folders)

fol2 can be fol21, fol22,.., (in 'fol1', there are multiple folders)

fol3 can be fol31, fol32,.. etc

None of the parent folder has files, only leaf folder has files. I want to get full path of all only leaf folder (not files).

I tried os.walk() but it gives all folder paths.

```
    dirName = '/home/mydir' 
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
         print(dirpath)
```

Output using os.walk()

> main/
>
> main/fol11/
>
> main/fol11/fol12
>
> ..
>
> main/fol12
>
> main/fol12/fol21 etc.

Expected output:

> main/fol11/fol21/fol31
>
> main/fol11/fol21/fol32
>
> main/fol11/fol22/fol31 .. etc (no file names)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58020924/edit) your question and included what you've tried.

Comment: I tried os.walk(). And I am searching that what to try but not able to find anything. Most of the answers include full file path.

Comment: What do you mean by leaf folders anyway?

Comment: The last folder in the chain. Ok I edit my question if it is confusing.

Comment: Please. And edit the directory into a neater one

Comment: Can you include your `os.walk()` code here?